# edit content xml file use JDOM2

Tags: java, xml, jdom, jdom-2

I want to ask your advice in next situation. I have xml file with goods. Goods can be not in stock ( in this case I use `<not-in-stock/>` empty-tag) or in stock (in this case I use tag `<price>value_price</price>` and dont use tag `<not-in-stock/>`).

I try to edit data in jsp page. I have just one idea: get value of element price by name, if value is empty I change name of element on not-in-stock.

If you know better decision  - write here.

```
ElementFilter filter=new org.jdom2.filter.ElementFilter("price");
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();

 for(Element c : root.getDescendants(filter))
 {
   elements.add(c);
 }

 if(!elements.isEmpty()){
 for(Element elementForUpdate : elements){
     elementForUpdate.setName("not-in-stock");
     elementForUpdate.setText(""); //I dont know value for empty-tag <not-in-stock/>
     XMLOutputter output=new XMLOutputter();
     output.output(doc, new FileOutputStream(file));
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search `<not-in-stock/>` node from the document object, set/modify text/name and save it.

```
 ElementFilter filter=new org.jdom2.filter.ElementFilter("not-in-stock");
 Element searchElement=null;
 for(Element c:root.getDescendants(filter))
 {
   searchElement=c;
   break;
 }
 if(searchElement!=null){
     searchElement.setName("NewName");
     searchElement.setText("Something is diff");
     XMLOutputter output=new XMLOutputter();
     output.output(doc, new FileOutputStream(file));
 }
```

Comment: You make a mistake in first row because I should make a filter for price. How do you think if I have in xml-file more than 1 element which has <price/> , it's normal if I put smth like that (see edited version)

Comment: @Ray - I don't know what *is* the structure of XML document so far but  just use *this* snippet for reference.

Comment: Do you agree with decision above?

Comment: it works, but I get tag <not-in-stock></not-in-stock>, but I want like this <not-in-stock/>